# Show another row of tabs when we click on a tab

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am developing a page using HTML, CSS and Javascript. In this one, I want to show the tabs "app1", "app2" and "app3" and their respective cards, only when we click on the tab "By APP" in the first row. Here's the code I tried.

```js
<script>
function openApp(evt, appName) {
 var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

 // Hide all tab content
 tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
 for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
   tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
 }

 // Deactivate all tab links
 tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
 for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
   tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
 }

 // Show the selected tab content
 document.getElementById(appName).style.display = "block";

 // Activate the clicked tab link
 evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
</script>
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial;
}

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #282828;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
 Padding: 15px 18.8px;
    width: 15.9%;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 14px;
  color:#97baba;
  font-weight:600;
}
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #cccccc;
  color:#ffffff;
}

.tab button.active:after,
.tab button:hover:after {
  opacity: 0;
}


.tab button:hover{
-webkit-animation-name: hvr-push;
  animation-name: hvr-push;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
   background-color: #ffffff;
   color:#3d8080;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes hvr-push {
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes hvr-push {
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
.Heading{
text-align:center;
color: #282828;
}

a{
  text-decoration:none;
}

.no{
  color:#c0392b;
}
.not_available{
  color:gray;
}
.btn1{
  outline:none;
  border:0;
  background:#1e5b67;
  padding:16px 7px;
  border-radius:4px;
  text-align:center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width:150px;
  color:#fff;
  transition:0.5s;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.btn1:hover{
  background:#282828;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 20px 26px;
  height: 414px;
}

/* Remove extra left and right margins, due to padding */
.row {margin: 0 -5px;}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Responsive columns */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}

/* Style the counter cards */
.card {
    box-shadow: 0 20px 40px -14px rgb(0 0 0 / 25%);
    padding: 5px 12px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 255px;
}
li a.course{
text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
h3{
color:#1e5b67;}
p{
color:#282828;}
span.session_duration{
    justify-content: left;
    display: flex;
        color: #282828;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial;
    }
.card:hover {
    transform: translate(0, -5px);
}
.tab-row {
 overflow: hidden;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 background-color: #282828;
 margin-top: 10px;
}

.tab-row button {
 background-color: inherit;
 float: left;
 border: none;
 outline: none;
 padding: 15px 18.8px;
 width: 15.9%;
 transition: 0.3s;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #97baba;
 font-weight: 600;
}

.tab-row button.active {
 background-color: #cccccc;
 color: #ffffff;
}

.tab-row button.active:after,
.tab-row button:hover:after {
 opacity: 0;
}

/* Additional styles for the new row of tabs */
.row .tab-row {
 width: 100%;
 float: none;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="Heading"><h2>Sessions</h2></div>
<br/>
<div class="tab">
<div class="tab_items" style="margin-left: 60px;">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openApp(event, 'date')" id="defaultOpen">By Date</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openApp(event, 'Podcasts')">Podcasts</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openApp(event, 'product')" id="defaultOpen">Mktng</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openApp(event, 'app')">Apps</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openApp(event, 'tools')">Tools</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openApp(event, 'stories')">Stories</button>
  
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="tab-row">
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openApp(event, 'app1')">App 1</button>
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openApp(event, 'app2')">App 2</button>
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openApp(event, 'app3')">App 3</button>
</div>
</div>
<div id="date" class="tabcontent">
<div class="row">

   <ul class="courses">
    <li><a class="product"><b>2023</b></a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="" class="course" target="_blank">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="course" target="_blank">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="course" target="_blank">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    

    </ul>
   
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="product" class="tabcontent">
<div class="row">
<div class="column">
 <a class=".btn1" href="" target="_blank">
  <div class="card">
    <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
     <p style="height: 155px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <br/><br/>
    </div>
    </a>
  </div>
<div class="column">
 <a class=".btn1" href="" target="_blank">
  <div class="card">
    <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
     <p style="height: 155px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <br/><br/>
    </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  </div>  
</div>

<div id="app" class="tabcontent">
<div id="app1" class="tabcontent">
<div class="row">
<div class="column">
 <a class=".btn1" href="" target="_blank">
  <div class="card">
    <h3>app 1 Lorem Ipsum</h3>
     <p style="height: 155px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <br/><br/>
    </div>
    </a>
  </div>
<div class="column">
 <a class=".btn1" href="" target="_blank">
  <div class="card">
    <h3>app 1 Lorem Ipsum</h3>
     <p style="height: 155px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <br/><br/>
    </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  </div>  
  <div id="app2" class="tabcontent">
<div class="row">
<div class="column">
 <a class=".btn1" href="" target="_blank">
  <div class="card">
    <h3>app 2 Lorem Ipsum</h3>
     <p style="height: 155px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <br/><br/>
    </div>
    </a>
  </div>
<div class="column">
 <a class=".btn1" href="" target="_blank">
  <div class="card">
    <h3>app 2 Lorem Ipsum</h3>
     <p style="height: 155px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <br/><br/>
    </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  </div>
  <div id="app3" class="tabcontent">
<div class="row">
<div class="column">
 <a class=".btn1" href="" target="_blank">
  <div class="card">
    <h3>app 3 Lorem Ipsum</h3>
     <p style="height: 155px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <br/><br/>
    </div>
    </a>
  </div>
<div class="column">
 <a class=".btn1" href="" target="_blank">
  <div class="card">
    <h3>app 3 Lorem Ipsum</h3>
     <p style="height: 155px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <br/><br/>
    </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  </div>
</div>

<div id="tools" class="tabcontent">
<div class="row">
<div class="column">
 <a class=".btn1" href="" target="_blank">
  <div class="card">
    <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
     <p style="height: 155px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <br/><br/>
    </div>
    </a>
  </div>
<div class="column">
 <a class=".btn1" href="" target="_blank">
  <div class="card">
    <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
     <p style="height: 155px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <br/><br/>
    </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  </div>  
</div>

<div id="stories" class="tabcontent">
<div class="row">
<div class="column">
 <a class=".btn1" href="" target="_blank">
  <div class="card">
    <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
     <p style="height: 155px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <br/><br/>
    </div>
    </a>
  </div>
<div class="column">
 <a class=".btn1" href="" target="_blank">
  <div class="card">
    <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
     <p style="height: 155px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <br/><br/>
    </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  </div>  
</div>
```

I am not able to hide the second layer of tabs and show only when we click on "by apps" tab. I wanted to show only the cards that are under app1, app2 and app3, only when we click on the respective tabs and when we click on the "By App" tab, make the "app1 tab" as default. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

use jquery toggle:
when you click the "Toggle Content" button, it will show/hide the content enclosed within the  element. The initial state is set to display: none in the CSS, so the content is hidden by default. The jQuery code handles the click event on the button and toggles the visibility of the content using the toggle() function.

```js
function openApp(evt, appName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

  // Hide all tab content
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  // Deactivate all tab links
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  // Show the selected tab content
  document.getElementById(appName).style.display = "block";

  // Activate the clicked tab link
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  // Handle click event on toggle button
  $('#toggle-button').click(function() {
    // Toggle the visibility of the content
    $('.content').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #282828;
  margin-top: 0px;
}




/* Style the buttons inside the tab */

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  Padding: 15px 18.8px;
  width: 15.9%;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #97baba;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #cccccc;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.tab button.active:after,
.tab button:hover:after {
  opacity: 0;
}

.tab button:hover {
  -webkit-animation-name: hvr-push;
  animation-name: hvr-push;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #3d8080;
}

@-webkit-keyframes hvr-push {
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes hvr-push {
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.Heading {
  text-align: center;
  color: #282828;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.no {
  color: #c0392b;
}

.not_available {
  color: gray;
}

.btn1 {
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  background: #1e5b67;
  padding: 16px 7px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 150px;
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.5s;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.btn1:hover {
  background: #282828;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 20px 26px;
  height: 414px;
}


/* Remove extra left and right margins, due to padding */

.row {
  margin: 0 -5px;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* Responsive columns */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}


/* Style the counter cards */

.card {
  box-shadow: 0 20px 40px -14px rgb(0 0 0 / 25%);
  padding: 5px 12px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
  height: 255px;
}

li a.course {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

h3 {
  color: #1e5b67;
}

p {
  color: #282828;
}

span.session_duration {
  justify-content: left;
  display: flex;
  color: #282828;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.card:hover {
  transform: translate(0, -5px);
}

.tab-row {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #282828;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.tab-row button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 15px 18.8px;
  width: 15.9%;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #97baba;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.tab-row button.active {
  background-color: #cccccc;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.tab-row button.active:after,
.tab-row button:hover:after {
  opacity: 0;
}


/* Additional styles for the new row of tabs */

.row .tab-row {
  width: 100%;
  float: none;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Heading">
  <h2>Sessions</h2>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="tab">
  <div class="tab_items" style="margin-left: 60px;">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openApp(event, 'date')" id="defaultOpen">By Date</button>
    <button class="tablinks">Podcasts</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openApp(event, 'product')" id="defaultOpen">Mktng</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openApp(event, 'app')" id="toggle-button">Apps</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openApp(event, 'tools')">Tools</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openApp(event, 'stories')">Stories</button>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="tab-row content">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openApp(event, 'app1')">App 1</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openApp(event, 'app2')">App 2</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openApp(event, 'app3')">App 3</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="date" class="tabcontent">
  <div class="row">

    <ul class="courses">
      <li><a class="product"><b>2023</b></a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="" class="course" target="_blank">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
          <li><a href="" class="course" target="_blank">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
          <li><a href="" class="course" target="_blank">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>


    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="product" class="tabcontent">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <a class=".btn1" href="" target="_blank">
        <div class="card">
          <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
          <p style="height: 155px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <br/><br/>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <a class=".btn1" href="" target="_blank">
        <div class="card">
          <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
          <p style="height: 155px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <br/><br/>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<div id="app" class="tabcontent">
  <div id="app1" class="tabcontent">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column">
        <a class=".btn1" href="" target="_blank">
          <div class="card">
            <h3>app 1 Lorem Ipsum</h3>
            <p style="height: 155px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <br/><br/>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <a class=".btn1" href="" target="_blank">
          <div class="card">
            <h3>app 1 Lorem Ipsum</h3>
            <p style="height: 155px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <br/><br/>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div id="app2" class="tabcontent">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <a class=".btn1" href="" target="_blank">
            <div class="card">
              <h3>app 2 Lorem Ipsum</h3>
              <p style="height: 155px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <br/><br/>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <a class=".btn1" href="" target="_blank">
            <div class="card">
              <h3>app 2 Lorem Ipsum</h3>
              <p style="height: 155px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <br/><br/>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div id="app3" class="tabcontent">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="column">
            <a class=".btn1" href="" target="_blank">
              <div class="card">
                <h3>app 3 Lorem Ipsum</h3>
                <p style="height: 155px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <br/><br/>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="column">
            <a class=".btn1" href="" target="_blank">
              <div class="card">
                <h3>app 3 Lorem Ipsum</h3>
                <p style="height: 155px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <br/><br/>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="tools" class="tabcontent">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="column">
            <a class=".btn1" href="" target="_blank">
              <div class="card">
                <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
                <p style="height: 155px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <br/><br/>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="column">
            <a class=".btn1" href="" target="_blank">
              <div class="card">
                <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
                <p style="height: 155px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <br/><br/>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="stories" class="tabcontent">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="column">
            <a class=".btn1" href="" target="_blank">
              <div class="card">
                <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
                <p style="height: 155px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <br/><br/>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="column">
            <a class=".btn1" href="" target="_blank">
              <div class="card">
                <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
                <p style="height: 155px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <br/><br/>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: I want to hide that second layer of the tab when we click on any of the tabs in the first row, not just when we click on the "By App" tab. Also, when we click on the "By App" tab, it should show the contents in the "App 1" tab by default and the content of "App 2" and "App3" when we click on "App 2" and "App 3" respectively

Comment: Can you clarify? When you click which class do you want to hide which class? ypu can apply the jquery toggle function anywhere in your code